# Class interface as module interface

Tags: python

What I want to achieve is to have `class Foo` interface at module level.

```
# foo.py
class Foo():
    def fun(self):
        pass

fun():
    return Foo().fun()  # this is what I want to avoid
                        # since module and class have
                        # the same interface

# module_scope_name = Foo()  # this is what I want to achieve

# SOLUTION:
fun = Foo().fun


# usage
import foo
foo.fun()
```

Comment: Why have a class in the first place then? Just define a bunch of functions and global variables.

Comment: currently your code won't even work, since you can't have a member function that doesn't have at least the self parameter. you MUST either declare them as `@staticmethod` or `@classmethod` which you can learn about here: http://stackabuse.com/pythons-classmethod-and-staticmethod-explained/ but if you do that there is no point in having it both inside and outside of the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stop writing classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0).

#### foo.py:

```
def fun():
    pass
```

#### Usage:

```
import foo
foo.fun()
```

Comment: Cool I like my class. What I want is to hide it as like it was a module. Is it possible or not?

Comment: What about putting `fun = Foo().fun` in the module?

Comment: Exactly. Thanks a lot :)